# MySql client: Difference between -p and --password

Tags: mysql, shell

The following commands give me different results:

```
mysql -u myuser -h my.database.server -p=mypass mydatabase
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'11.22.33.44' (using password: YES)

mysql -u myuser -h my.database.server --password=mypass mydatabase
> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g... etc
```

I understand this two options are equivalent as stated by `mysql --help`:

> -p, --password[=name] 
>                         Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
>                         not given it's asked from the tty.

I tried quoting the password when using `-p` with single and double quotes. Anyone knows what is the difference between this two ways to provide the password and where is it documented?

Adding the `-p` without the `=` just prompts for the pass from stdin, but it doesn't prompt when I add the `=`, so I assume it is consuming the password but somehow parsing it wrong.

Comment: [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-names.html): `[...]If you use the -p option, there must be no space between -p and the following password value.[...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there's no strict requirement for how command-line options work, they're often left to the whim of whomever is developing the software, there are two strong conventions. There's the "single letter" style, like `-p`, and the long-form, like `--password`.

By convention single letter options do not use the `=` method. They're employed like:

```
-pmypassword
```

That's not exceptionally readable, so the long-form version is preferred:

```
--password=mypassword
```

The `-p` option for `mysql` seems to be a simple trigger for requesting input unless you mash on the actual password, while the long-form version either triggers or if there's an `=` part it will add that as the password, plus berate you for using passwords on the command-line.

One reason behind this relative consistency is the presence of libraries like GNU's [`getopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt) which can handle both long and short arguments. Anyone who rolls their own argument processing library may take a different approach.

Now most tools follow this style, but there are some, like `find` and `openssl`, where all that goes out the window.